# YouTube shows black/white loading screen in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am developing a cross platform application using Cordova.

I am using an embedded YouTube video within the application.

When I tap play on the video the thumbnail image of the video disappears and a black / white loading screen emerges, shown below.

This does not occur when I test the application in Google Chrome or Safari, only when I run the application on a device (in this case an S4).

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to restore the default black loading screen?

[image: Black and white loading screen]

Comment: In your phone,Have you install youtube app?

Comment: Hey, yea I do have the YouTube app installed. If it's loading into an iframe, does that matter?

Comment: Did you found solution for it?

Comment: Nah, i have seen this image while loading YouTube in a lot of other situations as well. Not sure if it's even possible to fix.